# Checkbox Selected Index is selected

Tags: c#, if-statement, messagebox, selectedindex

I have a simple IF statement in my code that i want to prompt the user if the item in index 2 of my checkedlistbox1 is selected.

It works when index 2 by itself is selected BUT does not work when other items including index 2 are checked in my checklist box. Below is what i have that works, now i just need it to work when 2 and others are selected.

```
if (checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Note to send email", "Note", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CheckedListBox.CheckedIndices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkedindices%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

> Collection of checked indexes in this CheckedListBox.

```
foreach(int index in checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices)
{
  if(index == 2)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Note to send email", "Note", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace that code with

```
if (checkedListBox1.SelectedIndices.Contains(2))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Note to send email", "Note", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

That will check if 2 is among all selected items.

See more on `SelectedIndices` property on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindices%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Use `SelectedIndices` instead of `SelectedIndex`, it returns a collection of the selected indices. Just make sure that `2` is in there.